# Append the sum of two values input in an empty list while true

Tags: python, function

I've been learning python for a while and I'm creating a program that prompts the user for two numbers. If the sum of the two values is a prime number print a message that the result is a prime number and append it to an empty list called prime_result, otherwise print a message that is not a prime number and doesn't append anything.

The problem is that when the program ask again for the two numbers, the previously added value is not saved and adds a new number, It can't append multiple values. I'm stuck in that and i don't know where I have to write that conditional.

Here is the code:

```
def PrimeNumber():

    while True:
        prime_result = []
        num1 = int(input("Give me the first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Give me the second number: "))
        result = num1 + num2

        if result == 1:
            print("The result of the sum is not a prime!")
        elif result > 1:
            for i in range(2, result):
                if result % i == 0:
                    print("The result of the sum is not a prime!")
                    break
            else:
                print("The result of the sum is a prime!")
                prime_result.append(result)
                print(f"Sum results: {prime_result}")
        else:
            print("The result of the sum is not a prime!")


PrimeNumber()
```

Comment: Heads-up: There's an indentation error here, but I'm unsure if it was present in the original code or was an artifact of how OP posted it here...

Comment: There are many ways to determine if a number is prime. This is the worst possible technique. Also, move *prime_result = []* outside (before) the *while* loop. What is the point of accumulating values in *prime_result* anyway? You never do anything with it

Comment: @DarkKnight Hey thanks for your answer, do you know and easy way to determine a prime number, please let me know below this comment, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating `prime_result` inside the while, so every time the loop iterates, it creates the list again. Just create it before the while:

```
def PrimeNumber():

    prime_result = []
    while True:
```